# Multiple threads writing, one thread reading from queue, thread safety

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I've had little experience in the past with concurrent threading, so I need a bit of help here.

Basically, what I have is a Queue (whether managed as a singleton by DI frameworks or in a static object). I also have multiple threads that need to write to that queue, however just one thread will ever dequeue.

Due to my slight lack of experience on thread safety, do I need to do something specific to ensure that something doesn't accidentally go awry? Considering one of the requirements is for the queued objects to be in the exact order they were sent to the queueing class in the first place.

I presume that having to use ConcurrentQueue is a must? Or will I have to start doing my own magic with queueing and locking?

Comment: ConcurrentQueue or BlockingCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ConcurrentQueue`, there's really not much additional work to do regarding the queueing. Don't roll your own unless you're really forced to, multi threading is *hard* to get right, and not at all fun to debug.

Just keep in mind that if you have multiple writers, there may be no strict order of data being inserted, that is, if one thread tries to add "A" and one thread tries to add "B", the order they get added in could end up different with just slight variations in timing.

Comment: Okay and this is where it begins to get interesting - I sort of need to have both of them inserted in that very specific order they were created (millisecond precision at the very least). Any possible solutions to that?

Comment: @NeroS That would require some semi advanced syncronisation (ie threads need to wait with the insert until threads _started before_ have completed insertion.) It would seem that [reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) with its schedulers may be have a more or less out-of-the-box solution for your problem, which otherwise may be a bit complex to solve.

Comment: @NeroS - make the requirement go away?   Why do say you need 'millisecond precision at the very least', because you are not going to get it in any sort of reliable way on a desktop OS.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentQueue is a good start and probably all you need to know to make it work. Watch out for other resources that might be shared between your threads that will need locking or using specialized concurrent classes.